# Problem regarding inheritance in python classes

Tags: python

I am trying to inherit methods from one a base class to another class, specifically the `__str__` method, where I only need to change it a little by adding a note.
Something like this.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return ' Name: ' + str(self.name)
```

And my second class.

```
class AnnotatedPerson(Person):
   def __init__(self, name=None, note=None):
       super().__init__(name=None)
       self.note = note

   def __str__(self):
       return ' Name: ' + str(self.name) + 'Note:' + str(self.note)
```

However this is not working, when printing `print(AnnotatedPerson.__str__())` on an object I only get the part `note` and the `name` part in the `__str__` method is set to `None` for objects that do have a value.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Just pointing out that you shouldn't need to call `__str__` explicitly in this case.  `print(annotated_person_instance)` will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
class AnnotatedPerson(Person):
   def __init__(self, name=None, note=None):
      super().__init__(name=None)
```

You are passing `None` as the value of the `name` argument, instead of passing  through the argument you got.  You just need:

```
      super().__init__(name)
```

This is an important point.  When you say

```
     ...(name=name,...)
```

The first one is the name of an argument in the function being called.  The second one is the name of a local variable in the function doing the calling.  So:

```
     ...(name=None,...)
```

doesn't mention the local variable at all.  It just forces a value into the function being called.

Answer (score 0):

You've been pass None to variables, soo you have no results from them, below the code i'm using using the string repr from Person.

```
class AnnotatedPerson(Person):
   def __init__(self, name=None, mother=None, father=None, born=None, died=None, note=None) -> None:
      super().__init__(name, mother, father, born, died)                # pass the arguments directly
      self.note=note

   def __str__(self) -> str:
       return f'{super().__str__()} Note: {self.note}'                # Here you have to pass only string representation from super().__str__() and add the note variable

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj1 = AnnotatedPerson("Gerson", "Maria", "José", "19/12/1975","02/02/2022","Died like a wild horse")
    print(obj1)

#Name: Gerson Note: Died like a wild horse
```

Here a thread with a semelhant question:

[python multiple inheritance passing arguments to constructors using super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34884567/python-multiple-inheritance-passing-arguments-to-constructors-using-super)