# How can I add an additional class inheritance to an existing one, but with different number of arguments to existing inheritance?

Tags: python, class

I have an existing class `TSEparser` that inherits from a parent `class Subparser`, but now I want to add another parent class (`SubparserMixin`) to `class TSEparser`. However, the problem is that the arguments passed by the initial inheritance gets in the way of this new inheritance- how can I fix this?

i.e:

```
class Subparser: 
    def __init__(self, filename, data_group, **kwargs):
        self.data_group = data_group
        self.filename = filename
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


class TSEparser(Subparser):
    def __init__(self, filename, data_group, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(filename, data_group, **kwargs)
```

Now I want to add another parent class SubparserMixin so we have `class TSEparser(Subparser, SubparserMixin)`, however Subparsermixin looks like this:

```
class SubparserMixin:

    def __init__(self):
        self.subparsers = {}
        self.context = PacketContext
```

Is there some way I can inherit separately from both Parent Classes? Something like this:

```
class TSEparser(Subparser):
    def __init__(self, filename, data_group, **kwargs):
        super(Subparser).__init__(filename, data_group, **kwargs)
        super(SubparserMixin).__init__()
```

I know the syntax is not correct but I hope it is clear what I am trying to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify which class' constructor gets called by simply using its name. So in your example you can just do

```
class TSEparser(Subparser, SubparserMixin):
    def __init__(self, filename, data_group, **kwargs):
        Subparser.__init__(self, filename, data_group, **kwargs)
        SubparserMixin.__init__(self)
```

There is no good and easy way to make this work using `super`. You can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34884567/python-multiple-inheritance-passing-arguments-to-constructors-using-super) for more detail. `super` normally takes care of calling the proper classes for you. If you want to call the `__init__` of a specific class manually (e.g. because the required arguments are different), you need to call it directly using its name as shown above.

**Edit**: My code example mistakenly didn't pass `self` when calling the base `__init__` methods. Note that this is a difference between calling by `super` and directly by base class. `super` doesn't require `self`, while direct calling does.

```
# without self
super().__init__()
# with self
Base.__init__(self)
```

Comment: Fllip, could you please post the whole class? As I am not sure what to do with the `def __init__` at the start of the class

Comment: Noted on your comment on super, but what about the def __init__? How can I write out the whole class. Is it just `def __init__(self)` ?

Comment: Updated the answer. You still need to receive the arguments in the child's `__init__`