# Python Multiple Inheritance super().__init__()

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have two classes, with the same parameter initialized by their `__init__` method.
I would like to inherit both classes in class "X". But I will get: `TypeError: B.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'my_param'`

Reproducible Example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, my_param):
        super().__init__()
        self.my_param = my_param


class B:
    def __init__(self, my_param):
        super().__init__()
        self.my_param = my_param * 2


class X(A, B):
    def __init__(self, my_param):
        super().__init__(my_param=my_param)

a = X(my_param=1)
print(a.my_param)
```

A and B are Mixins, they provide additional functionality for Child Classes. They can be used separetly or together. Lets's say class A provides searhc functionality for search by ID, where class B provides search by value.

Is there a way to set my_param for each of A and B or to set it without getting the error?

Comment: I would comment out `super().__init__()` call in `A` constructor method

Comment: X calls A with the parameter, but then A calls B without it. Your parent classes need to be written to collaborate in the inheritance.

Comment: so A and B are not related to each other? i.e. I assume it wouldn't make sense to inherit one from the other?

Comment: also, note that class `Abstract` is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can't be done just using `super()` calls, because the superclass of the last class in the chain will be `object`, which doesn't take a `my_param` parameter.

See [python multiple inheritance passing arguments to constructors using super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34884567/python-multiple-inheritance-passing-arguments-to-constructors-using-super) for more discussion of parameter passing to `__init__()` methods with multiple inheritance.

So you need to change `X` to call the superclass init methods explicitly, rather than using `super()`. And `A` and `B` shouldn't call `super().__init__()` because they're subclasses of `object`, which doesn't do anything in its `__init__()`.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, my_param):
        self.my_param = my_param

class B:
    def __init__(self, my_param):
        self.my_param = my_param * 2

class X(A, B):
    def __init__(self, my_param):
        A.__init__(self, my_param=my_param)
        B.__init__(self, my_param=my_param)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!, Unfortunately when I try this, I get the error: ´TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)` I

Comment: ahhh, thank you so much for the explanation! I tried to solve it in the meantime by creating an abstract class shared by A and B but it feels not really clean, I definetly can use your solution and learned something new on the way, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Since `A` and `B` share the same fields, I think it makes sense to make one inherit from the other - in this case, `B` inherit from `A`. That way, you'll only need to subclass from `B` in class `X`.

For example:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, my_param):
        self.my_param = my_param


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, my_param):
        super().__init__(my_param * 2)
        # or:
        #   A.__init__(self, my_param * 2)


class X(B):
    def __init__(self, my_param):
        super().__init__(my_param=my_param)


a = X(my_param=1)
print(a.my_param)  # 2
```

Comment: This class hierarchy may not make sense for the rest of the behavior of B.

Comment: Totally right, I did make an assumption that since B and A share the same field, it might make sense to introduce some sort of inheritance. But I agree that this might not be the best idea, depending on the use case or scenario.

Comment: @rv.kvetch thank you for your answer, class A and B are Mixins, they provided different functunalities e.g. search by value (A) and search by id (B). Some childs of A and B only need A as parent, some only B and some both. But both classes share some attributes.