# Super method for python multi class inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I'm trying to create a daughter class that inherits from two parent classes, each of which has its own required inputs. However, when I try to initialize the daughter class I am getting an error that says it has the wrong number of inputs.

```
class A(object):
   def __init__(self, a=0, a1=0, a2=0):
      self.a = a
      self.a1 = a1
      self.a2 = a2

class B(object):
   def __init__(self, b=0, b1=0, b2=0):
      self.b = b
      self.b1 = b1
      self.b2 = b2

class C(A, B):
   def __init__(self, a, a1, a2, b, b1, b2):
      super().__init__(a, a1, a2, b, b1, b2)
```

but when I initialize `C` the following way:

```
c = C(a=1, a1=1, a2=1, b=2, b1=2, b2=2)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: A.__init__() takes from 1 to 4 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

What is the correct way to have multi class inheritance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python multiple inheritance passing arguments to constructors using super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34884567/python-multiple-inheritance-passing-arguments-to-constructors-using-super)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by the comment, it requires to adapt the base classes and it can become quite complicated as MRO (method resolution order) becomes involved to resolve the calls to `super()` (see [python multiple inheritance passing arguments to constructors using super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34884567/python-multiple-inheritance-passing-arguments-to-constructors-using-super) for more details)

However, it is ususally a strong code smell that you should not use inheritance but composition:

```py
class C:
  def __init__(self, a, a1, a2, b, b1, b2):
    self.a_instance = A(a, a1, a2)
    self.b_instance = B(b, b1, b2)
```

Your class `C` can then act like a wrapper around the functionalities provided by the classes `A` and `B`

Answer (score 1):

2 things here:

- super() will follow the [method resolution order](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-resolution-order-in-python-inheritance/#) meaning only `A.__init__` is being called when you call `super().__init__`
- you can still roughly accomplish what you need here using dictionary argument unpacking (after resolving the inheritance issue)

```py
class A(object):
   def __init__(self, a=0, a1=0, a2=0):
      self.a = a
      self.a1 = a1
      self.a2 = a2
      print("a")

class B(object):
   def __init__(self, b=0, b1=0, b2=0):
      self.b = b
      self.b1 = b1
      self.b2 = b2
      print("b")

class C(A, B):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      for klass in self.__class__.__mro__:
         super(klass, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```